# Enumerating modules cannot deallocate the allocated space and duplicate module names

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm enumerating all DLL modules in a process, but there are two issues:

#### #1 Duplicate records

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume4\AC\Debug\AC.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
```

#### #2 NtFreeVirtualMemory doesn't deallocate the whole space it allocated.

- Before NtFreeVirtualMemory call

[image]

- After it. You can see how it left all those regions.

[image]

#### Code

```cpp
bool enumerate_modules()
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi{};

    const std::size_t buffer_size = 512;
    void* base_address = 0;
    std::size_t region_size = buffer_size;
    
    NTSTATUS status = NtAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &base_address, 0, &region_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return false;

    const auto& section_name = reinterpret_cast<PMEMORY_SECTION_NAME>(base_address);
    
    SYSTEM_INFO si{};

    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    
    auto* min_address = static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(si.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
    auto* max_address = static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress);
    
    while (min_address < max_address)
    {
        status = NtQueryVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), min_address, MemoryBasicInformation, &mbi, sizeof mbi, nullptr);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
            break;

        if (mbi.Type == MEM_IMAGE)
        {
            status = NtQueryVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), min_address, MemoryMappedFilenameInformation, section_name, buffer_size, nullptr);

            if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
                break;

            const auto& dll = section_name->SectionFileName.Buffer;

            printf("%S\n", dll);
        }

        min_address += mbi.RegionSize;
    }
    
    region_size = 0;

    status = NtFreeVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &base_address, &region_size, MEM_RELEASE);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `if (mbi.Type == MEM_IMAGE)` main wrong condition. must be `if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Type == MEM_IMAGE && mbi.AllocationBase == mbi.BaseAddress)` than `min_address += mbi.RegionSize;` also wrong, despite usual work as excepted. more correct use `min_address = (PBYTE)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;` and many other things. code is very not optimal

Answer (score 1):

"I'm enumerating all DLL modules in a process"

Well, you're not. That's what `EnumProcessModules` does. You enumerate memory regions.

As for the remaining pages; you didn't `DECOMMIT` them.

Note that these `Nt` functions are very low-level and assume that you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Well, this is supposed to be an AC and there might be hidden DLLs, which makes the Nt functions mandatory. I replaced `MEM_RELEASE` with `MEM_DECOMMIT`, but it's kinda the same.

Comment: @nop - no, must be `MEM_RELEASE` in call `NtFreeVirtualMemory` if you want free memory. but why you use here this api at all ? why 512 bytes ?? really you have many mistakes in implementation. correct implementation of course work ok

Comment: @RbMm, there might be a better way, I don't know, I'm using it to store the name e.g. (`\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll`)

Comment: @nop - why 512 size ?? why not 300 or 1049 ? why use `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` instead `LocalAloc` or `new` ? and correct implementation - https://pastebin.com/pU6zNTUb

Comment: @RbMm, thank you! Btw, which header file is `MAXUSHORT` taken from? Edit: Nvm, `USHRT_MAX` seems to be that one.

Comment: @nop - why you look for this absolute not important details ? *ntdef.h* formally. but you can not use this at all. this is demo code. i for example not ask you - where is  `PMEMORY_SECTION_NAME` - declared, despite this is not standard name at all

Comment: @RbMm, true. If you want, write that code as an answer, so I can accept it. That really helped me!